# Unable to Parse SOAP Response Using C#

Tags: c#, soap

The 1st SOAP Response is

```html
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:SfaaHeaderType xmlns:ns1=""https://ebilltest.wsdl"">
            <MsgType>RESPONSE</MsgType>
            <MsgClass>LOGIN</MsgClass>
            <InstitutionCode>01</InstitutionCode>
            <SecurityToken></SecurityToken>
            <Timestamp>20210813161313</Timestamp>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            <ResponseTo>1</ResponseTo>
        </ns1:SfaaHeaderType>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <logonResponse xmlns=""https://ebilltest.wsdl"">
            <SecurityToken xmlns="">eradicated</SecurityToken>
            <LoginTime xmlns="">20210813161313</LoginTime>
            <Timeout xmlns="">20210813164313</Timeout>
            <IdleTimeout xsi:type=""xsd:int"" xmlns="">1800</IdleTimeout>
        </logonResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have attempted to use both XDocument to Load the XML or XMLReader to Parse the XML,
but it returns Unhandled exception. System.Xml.XmlException: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 16, position 380.

I could not find the Error of '<'

Seeing Below a 2nd SOAP Response which is valid, able to parse

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""no""?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPSDK1=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:SOAPSDK2=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:SOAPSDK3=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">

    <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">
        <SOAPSDK4:GetStoreProductsResponse xmlns:SOAPSDK4=""http://www.externalwebservice.com/message/"">
            <StoreProducts>
                <StoreID>1</StoreID>
                <Products>Harry Potter Book1</Products>
            </StoreProducts>
        </SOAPSDK4:GetStoreProductsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The code I use to Parse the Valid SOAP Response is as follows

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);          
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.externalwebservice.com/message/";
            IEnumerable<XElement> responses = doc.Descendants(ns+"StoreProducts");
            foreach (XElement response in responses)
            {
                Console.Write((string)response.Element("Products"));

            }
            
            //Result Harry Potter Book1
```

Would anyone give some insight on how to parse the 1st SOAP Response?
When I plug all the values back , it does not even parse.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
//Unhandled exception. System.Xml.XmlException: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 16, position 380.

Comment: Each quotation mark is escaped (" -> "") except xmlns="" in your loginResponse elements. Try `xmlns=""""`

Comment: Thanks Michael , it works....
How silly for escaped quotes....

Answer (score 0):

The response is incorrect for xmlns=""
need to change to read xmlns=""""
because I am using String Literal
e.g.

```
String soapResult=@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns1:SfaaHeaderType xmlns:ns1=""https://ebilltest.wsdl"">
            <MsgType>RESPONSE</MsgType>
            <MsgClass>LOGIN</MsgClass>
            <InstitutionCode>15</InstitutionCode>
            <SecurityToken></SecurityToken>
            <Timestamp>20210813161313</Timestamp>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            <ResponseTo>1</ResponseTo>
        </ns1:SfaaHeaderType>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <logonResponse xmlns=""https://ebilltestwsdl"">
            <SecurityToken xmlns="""">hhhhh==</SecurityToken>
            <LoginTime xmlns="""">20210813161313</LoginTime>
            <Timeout xmlns="""">20210813164313</Timeout>
            <IdleTimeout xsi:type=""xsd:int"" xmlns="""">1800</IdleTimeout>
        </logonResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
```